# Calling a method in a fxml controller when the application is being closed, javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a gui that i'm creating for a college project. The project has a main class that loads a fxml file which is a login page and sets it as the scene. what I'm trying to do is call a method in the the login fxml controller when the red X button on the top right of the gui is clicked, the main class extends Application so i'm able to override the stop method in there but i cant find a way to call the method in login controller that i want to call when the tool is being exited. I know i can do this easily with an actually button but i need it to work on the X button to.

The reason i need to call this method is so i can store the info the user entered in the page into a text file. also using the FXMLLoader.load wont work aswell, as this creates a new instance of the fxml file which wont contain any of the details entered by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to obtain an instance of your controller class from the loader and store it for later use. Then you can call any method of your controller class from the stop method. In order to achieve this you also have to use an instance of the FXML loader to load your FXML and not the static load methods. From the instance of the FXML loader you can get your controller.